# Problem with Deleting node in BST (Binary Search Tree) function (code)

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, error-code

We know that there is two ways to delete node if he had two childs
in my exemple if we take the min of the maxs all is good
when we take the max of the mins  the program miss or remove a sub-tree of the node we remove.
On my code please.

I tried to do pointer of pointer in the functions and nothing changes.
I tried to do a pointer on the node we delete and do the process starting from it and still not working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct noeud Node;
struct noeud
{
    int valeur;
    Node *gauche;
    Node *droit;
};

Node *createNode(int val)
{
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->valeur = val;
    newNode->gauche = NULL;
    newNode->droit = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void infixe(Node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    infixe(root->gauche);
    printf("%d - ",root->valeur);
    infixe(root->droit);
}

Node* findMin(Node* root){
    Node* current=root;
    while(current->gauche!=NULL)
        current=current->gauche;

    return current;
}
Node* findMax(Node* root){
    Node* current=root;
    while(current->droit!=NULL)
        current=current->droit;

    return current;
}

Node* deleteInBST(Node* root,int val){
     
    if(root==NULL) return root;

    if(val<root->valeur){
        root->gauche=deleteInBST(root->gauche,val);
    }
    else if(val>root->valeur){
        root->droit=deleteInBST(root->droit,val);
    }
    else{
            //! here of the root we wanna delete hasn't gauche child so we take the droit and we delete the root
            if(root->gauche==NULL){
                Node* temp=root->droit;
                free(root);
                return temp;
            }   
            //! here of the root we wanna delete hasn't droit child so we take the gauche and we delete the root
            else if(root->droit==NULL){
                Node* temp=root->gauche;
                free(root);
                return temp;
            }
            else{
            //! here if the root has two child so we have 02 ways to do it 
                //! the first we take the min of the maxs
                /*Node* temp=findMin(root->droit);
                root->valeur=temp->valeur;
                root->droit=deleteInBST(root->droit,temp->valeur);
                //! the second we take the max of the mins 
                */
                Node* temp=findMax(root->gauche);
                root->valeur=temp->valeur;
                root->gauche=deleteInBST(root->gauche,temp->valeur);
                
                return root;
            }
    }
}


int main(){ 
    
    Node* root = createNode(25);
    root->gauche = createNode(10);
    root->droit = createNode(60);
    root->gauche->gauche = createNode(5);
    root->gauche->droit = createNode(20);
    root->gauche->droit->gauche = createNode(15);
    

    root->droit->gauche = createNode(35);
    root->droit->gauche->gauche = createNode(30);
    root->droit->gauche->droit = createNode(45);

    
    root->droit->gauche->droit->gauche = createNode(40);
    root->droit->gauche->droit->gauche->gauche = createNode(37);
    root->droit->gauche->droit->gauche->droit = createNode(43);


    root->droit->droit = createNode(65);
    root->droit->droit->droit = createNode(70);



    printf("\n");
    infixe(root);

    /*//! here if we do root=deleteInBST(root,60) we lose the tree if we keep it like i wrote it we lose the sub_tree of 60 in the 
        // !most left           */

    deleteInBST(root,60);
    printf("\n");
    infixe(root);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line to see what happens? I recommend you also use pencil and paper to draw the tree and the operations you do on it. Use labeled boxes for variables and nodes, and pointed arrows for links and pointers. Erase and redraw the arrows as the code modifies the corresponding pointers. That makes it very easy to visualize the tree and your operations on it. And to see when and where things might go wrong.

Comment: It would probably be a little more efficient to find and delete the max element at the same time, and perhaps less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your recursive function doesn't always execute a `return` statement. Notably in the case where the node with value `val` has not yet been found, you don't return the root after the recursive call has been made.

The solution is to move the last `return root;` statement out of the two nested `else` blocks so that it is also executed in the cases where `val` is different from `root->valeur`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing return values in two important cases. You should be getting a compiler warning.

```
    if(val<root->valeur){
        root->gauche=deleteInBST(root->gauche,val);
        return root;
    }
    else if(val>root->valeur){
        root->droit=deleteInBST(root->droit,val);
        return root;
    }
```